# Finding execution path leading to exception

Tags: python, unassigned-variable

My IDE is warning me against a possible **variable reference before assignment**. But I'm having trouble spotting it. I'm ready to turn in a bug report, but maybe you can see what I'm not seeing.

The variable in question is a named `check_dialog` and the *reference before assignment* warning happens at the end of the following code snippet in the line I marked for you:

```
    if dialog:
        validate = None
        string = False

        if dialog == Prompt.YES | Prompt.NO:
            check_dialog = lambda c: chr(c) in 'yn'
        elif dialog == Prompt.CONTINUE | Prompt.QUIT:
            check_dialog = lambda c: chr(c) in 'cq'
        elif dialog == Prompt.YES | Prompt.NO | Prompt.QUIT:
            check_dialog = lambda c: chr(c) in 'ynq'
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid dialog argument.')

    answer = None
    while not answer:
        self.addstr(0, 1, prompt)

        if string:
            curses.curs_set(True)
            curses.echo()
            answer = self.getstr(1, 3)
            curses.noecho()
            curses.curs_set(False)
        elif dialog:
            while not check_dialog(answer):  # warning here!
                answer = self.getch()
        else:
            answer = self.getch()
```

Comment: Probably because it sees that it is not assigned in the `else` above, so it isn't there in every case. However, since that else raises a ValueError, it makes no practical difference. Try something like `check_dialog = None` in that `else` to silence your IDE's warning, but it is safe to ignore.

Comment: Yeah. Tried that before. It spits a new warning that check_variable is not being used and also maintains the previous warning. Hehe :) Only way to silence it is to define check_dialog at the top before the first if statement. It's probably a bug

Comment: OK. I was just about to edit my comment saying you might need to define it before the first if, but it's for the same reason (that if has no else).

Comment: Oh, you mean the first if statement. Well, I suppose... But it still wouldn't make sense to declare it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE is not "thinking" about every possible value of your variables (in most cases, this would be impossible) and instead is using heuristics to prevent common mistakes. In this case, it has noticed that `check_dialog` is defined within an if condition, but not in every case. Yet it is used below this condition. That might be an `UnboundLocalError`!

As programmers, we can reason this out and see that the code paths it has noticed are protected. The `else` case raises a `ValueError` which will not be caught, and the usage is protected by `(el)if dialog` in both cases, so this will not be a problem.

It is not a bug in your IDE, because it is doing what it is supposed to. If it really bothers you and you can't otherwise silence the warning, you can unnecessarily define something like `check_dialog = None` over the top of the first `if dialog`, and it will shut up. However, it is also not a bug with your program/code, which as reasoned above will not cause an `UnboundLocalError`. This is safe to ignore, and because of how your IDE probably works a bug report would just be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try to fill the bug report nonetheless. If by any chance they are doing static analysis without any heuristics, it will classify as a false positive bug

Comment: Just be sure to search their bug database first for duplicates! :)